# VBA - Using Input Box value to Search Data Range

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to put together a code that will allow me to do a few things.

What I am looking to do is search for the value used in an input box in a column and auto increment the adjacent cell by 1.

Example, column A has a list of serial numbers. Column B tracks the number of "uses". The input box asks to input a serial number. When the serial number is input, I would like the code to search for the serial number in column A, move to column B in the same row, and increment that value +1. If the serial number is not found in column A, provide a "Not Found" message box.

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
Sub yourmacro()
Serialnumber = Application.InputBox("Please provide a serial number", "Serial Number", Type:=1)

Set found = Range("A:A").Find(what:=Serialnumber, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

If found Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Your serial number was not found"
Else
    found.Offset(0, 1).Value = found.Offset(0, 1).Value + 1
End If

End Sub
```

i'm assuming your serial number has no "-" or "/", just numbers (that's why the type 1 in the inputbox)